# Change Button's Action When Pressing On HTML

Tags: html

I have a script for this game:

```
<body>
<pre>
<p id="menuText1">Welcome To __________!</p> <!-- No name yet :P -->

<button onclick="menuButtonPressed1()" type="button" id="menuButton1">Cool, is this the whole game?</button>

<script>
function menuButtonPressed1() {
    document.getElementById("menuText1").innerHTML = "No, there's more!";
    document.getElementById("menuButton1").innerHTML = "Can I see it?";
}
</script>


</pre>
</body>
```

I know how to change the button's label but how do I change what the button actually does? I want to change it so different text shows up when you hit it for a second time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a counter global var that updates every time you press the button. Then based on that counter you can change the functionality.

https://jsfiddle.net/partypete25/zug4Lsfz/6/

```
<script>
var counter = 0;
function menuButtonPressed1() {
    counter += 1;
    var text = document.getElementById("menuText1");
    var button = document.getElementById("menuButton1");
    if (counter==1){
     text.innerHTML = "No, there's more!";
     button.innerHTML = "Can I see it?";
    } else if (counter==2){
     text.innerHTML = "Second time text";
     button.innerHTML = "second time button label";
    }
}    
</script>
```

Comment: Is this system repeatable? (For third time uses, four time uses, etc.)

Comment: yep, everytime the button is clicked, counter is increased by 1.

Comment: How do I get it to actually change stuff on those extra uses? Where do I place the "if" commands and stuff? (Sorry, I'm kinda getting used to html)

Comment: This is javaScript by the way. Very basic stuff. You could write, for example, if(counter==1) { //do this } else if (counter==2) {//do this} else if (counter==3) { //do this } else { // do this }. The last 'else' statement will be executed if all the previous conditions are false. You should read this for more information: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp. Depending on the changes you are trying to make after each click, you might want to use a 'switch' statement instead of an if/else conditional statement: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp

Comment: Thanks! This helped me a lot! I'm going to go study javaScript and stuff! Thanks again!